# How to access ContactStore in Shared project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Contact Store which is in Windows.ApplicationModel is accessable in windows phone 8.1 project but it is not accessible in my View model which is in my shared project. Does anyone know how to access this in shared project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Conditional Compilation Constants inside the Shared Project

```
#if WINDOWS_APP
     //do your logic here
#else
     //do windows phone logic here
#endif
```